# XPath : Pass attribute value down the path

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am wondering if below is achievable using xpath

Given:

```
 <label for="pt1:sc">Select Country</label>
 <select id="pt1:sc">....</select>
```

Requirement:

I want to find select element using single xpath expression like below, 
 bcs ids are dynamic and always available in attribute 'for'.

//label[text()='Select Country']/@for//*[@id=@for]

Can we pass attribute value(here for attribute of label) in xpath, further down the path to find element.

Please do not suggest alternative using siblings, child, id or selenium get-attribute etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to select an element with an attribute value which refers to another attribute located in another element :

```
//*[@id=//label[text()='Select Country']/@for]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's going to work with your actual html, but it works on the example in the question:

```
//label[text()='Select Country'][@for=//select/@id]
```